# Where to find the aircraft maintenance manual for the Falcon 2000?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

How can I find a Falcon 2000 aircraft maintenance  manual (AMM)?

Comment: [Resource location](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is off-topic, voted to close.

Comment: You should be getting this information from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the latest AMM through the Falcon Interactive Electronic Library by Dassault (FIELD). Contact the manufacturer [through their website](https://www.dassaultfalcon.com/en/Support/Product-services/Documentation/Pages/MaintenanceDocumentation.aspx) for pricing and information on how to setup an account.

Comment: @user29669 This is one of those situations where if you have to ask strangers on the internet how to do it, you shouldn't be doing it.